# Three-Column Gallery Layout

Tags: html, css, website-design

I've been trying to do the following 2 things, but have been unsuccessful. I know they're really simple, but I just can't seem to get them to work. Here's the [website](http://xeenat.com/lima) I started coding today.

1) I'm trying to make a 3-column gallery layout. It sounds so simple, but I have been unsuccessful so far. Not sure how to achieve this. I Google'd and came across various articles, but none of them were aligning properly. See the link provided. I want to have three 320px wide thumbnails. I tried creating lists, and floating divs. I could use a table, but aren't divs better now? Suggestions?

2) I'm trying to make it so each button in the menu has a different colour in hover and selected state. The other two are different pages, but I'm not sure how to change them and keep the same effect. I found the script [here](http://tutorialzine.com/2009/09/stylish-navigation-menu-jquery/).

I am new to this so any help is appreciated :)

Comment: If you want to know more about DIV vs TABLE for page layouts see [Why aren't we supposed to use <table> in a design?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/6036/1253). As for your second question, we can't help you unless know more about your problem. I suggest going to [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/), which is where coding questions are asked, and show what you've tried so far.