# Is using HTML tables for data presentation bad for SEO?

Tags: seo, table

I have a site that presents information in each page with HTML tables. 
Does this affect my site's SEO? Should I replace all tables with divs?

I'm not using HTML tables for layout. I'm only using them for representing information.

Comment: "Representing information" is pretty generic. We'd need  to see your data. If it's "tabular data", using `table` is correct. If not, not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, this will not harm your SEO. [Using tables for layout is frowned upon for various reasons](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6036/why-arent-we-supposed-to-use-table-in-a-design/6037#6037) but that doesn't mean you're never supposed to use them. They're meant to be used exactly as you're using them: for tabular data. If anything, this will help your SEO as it will help search engines understand your content better since your markup will be semantic.

Comment: In fact, I have seen Google show a few rows from a table in SERPs.

Comment: I am aware of these SEO benefits (rich snippets and scemantic markup) of using HTML tables on the page. However, my developers said if we use HTML tables then page won't stay mobile responsive. What should be done in this case? Is there any alternate available?